# Cross platform audio analysis library

Tags: audio, cross-platform, signal-processing

I'm looking for a cross-platform library that allows me to analyze the waveform of a sound file. It needs to be able to at least have the ability to query the amplitude for a given sample, and it would be nice if it could do frequency detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, querying the amplitude for a given sample is rather easy, you only need to convert the sample's value to decibels.  As for the other types of analysis, you'll probably find [aubio](http://aubio.org/) to be a good tool.  It can do frequency detection, and even gives you the option of using a number of different detection algorithms depending on whether you need accuracy or performance.

Comment: Looks promising. I'll give it a whirl. Thanks!