# Audio Processing in Java/C++

Tags: java, c++, audio

I am looking for a library that will allow me to work with sound. This is just something that occurred to me and the problem is that in a large music collection I need to find tracks similar to another reference track . The simplest of things would be to find tracks with the same/almost-the-same tempo . Is this possible and are there any tools available for this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657073/how-to-detect-bpm-of-the-song-by-programming

Comment: This may be a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708819/cross-platform-audio-analysis-library

Comment: What platform are you targeting? Linux? Windows? Something else?

Comment: Also, do you want a library for Java or for C++? There won't be a library that can be used for both.

Comment: @WoodrowDouglass It would seem so .. I'll see if aubio works out for me ..

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sure there will, you can call C libraries using JNI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding music which is similar to other music is quite a complex field, and will probably require quite a bit of work if you're willing to spend quite a bit of time. If Java is your language of choice, then you could have a look at [coMIRVA](http://www.cp.jku.at/people/schedl/Research/Development/CoMIRVA/webpage/CoMIRVA.html) which will let you compare music based on timbre.  From my experience, doing comparisons on that single dimensions isn't always good enough, but it is at least a start.

There's always the other path, which is to use an already existing commercial offering such as the Echo Nest and BMAT. I don't know what they cost, but it's probably quite pricey. However, these are products that have taken years to develop so I assume they must at least provide some sort of value.